# How to word an email about discrimination and ableism

Tags: united-states, email, discrimination

How do I professionally say “(name) has repetitively told me not to use the ‘I’m autistic’  excuse” when she asked, why I do things a certain way, or yells at me.

I also told them upon being hired that I have an over-active bladder, and I will need multiple bathroom breaks, she then proceeds to yell at me for taking said bathroom breaks.

How should I word this?

Comment: For legal actions, you need to contact your lawyer and they can guide you better.

Comment: Contacting a lawyer sounds like it's quite an escalation.  You stated the facts pretty clearly here, I don't see why you couldn't use this same wording in speaking to your manager (or HR if your manager is the problem person).

Comment: If this post is related to this, then follow the advice given there: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/196676/75821

Comment: @DaveG my comment is out of context now because my other comment has been deleted. I asked op what are wanting to get out of this. OP asked a similar question and people already advised not to write anything as this is only for an exit interview and they're likely to not take it seriously now. Or OP, file/should've filed a formal complaint with HR when they were facing it.

Comment: @DaveG And that's why I asked OP is it for self satisfaction? Or if OP wants to take legal actions. I think I came too strong on asking this and that's why my comment got deleted even though people were agreeing.

Comment: That does not mean I do not sympathize with OP. Absolutely no one, should ever face this and let this be an enlightenment experience for OP to always take timely actions instead to tolerating it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Have conversations about these types of things in person, not via email.

It seems appealing to be able to define and refine your words in a written document, but it will come off as sterile and possibly hostile.  Even NT people struggle to put contentious issues in writing.  These things are always better done in person, where your obvious discomfort is  discussing them will be an asset to the discussion.

Comment: As much as I'd love to talk face to face to an actual person, each time I ask I'm told to email someone.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your medical condition, it's not sufficient to dismiss criticism by simply stating you have that condition. You need to be prepared to work with your employer to decide on strategies that allow you to complete your job effectively, or adjust your role where required.

Without knowing specifics it's difficult to know how collaborative you both have been, and what the appropriate next step may be.

With respect to your toilet breaks, you simply need to make them aware that you disclosed this condition during the interview process, and this was decided to not be a problem. If they were not present during the interview process, you should indicate who explicitly you mentioned this to.

Comment: I do agree, but when the yelling starts the yelling is the issue.